# Buffer. Запись изображение в файл

Tags: node.js, byte

Изучаю бинарные данные. Не могу разобраться в следующем:

получаю изображение из сети:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');


var options = {
    url: 'url',
    // encoding: 'binary' // понимаю, что можно использовать, но хотелось бы самому..
}


request(options, function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

        var data = new Buffer(body);

        fs.writeFile('image.png', data, 'binary');

        console.log(data);
    }

})
```

вывод:

```
�PNG

IHDR

�2�4IDAT�5�=O�QF���.��"�%�:
                       �HLLH�|`��U��4�~�~   G       �
��/x��������qw��L&�v{|�����Kr���h6����E���R"x������>�j�q��Q���r�I,��|=9b�#
                                                                          ���,�N13$yY��.��^kL��������9&���<

�V�����}dsg����1�gQ�?��V6��W���vcI�;��pwJoj��;�����hb����E���)%r���$r�<�T�G�NIEND�B`�
```

После записи этих данных в локальный файл, изображение не хочет выводиться.

Интересует: **Что это за тип данных которые я получаю?** Разве это не бинарные данные? Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте 
request(options).pipe(
    fs.createWriteStream('image.png')
);
У меня все отлично работает